# why does syntax highlighting disable when I use web-mode in emacs?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

[image]

This is my init.el

```
 (require 'web-mode)

 (setq web-mode-tag-auto-close-style 1)

 (setq web-mode-enable-auto-closing t)
```

What should I do?

Comment: That's a screenshot of html-mode, not of web-mode.

Comment: Could be a bug in web-mode.  But while I'm here: I think you have a missing space between `(setq` and `web-mode-enable-auto-closing t)`.

Comment: Maybe you can try with another color theme (`M-x load-theme`). On the default one, I find web-mode to be low-contrast, html tags and text are displayed in light and dark grey, so maybe yours doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my misunderstanding. Only I didn't setup colors of web-mode.

Answer (score 0):

For example

'(web-mode-doctype-face
   ((t (:foreground "#4A8ACA"))))
 '(web-mode-html-tag-face
   ((t (:foreground "#4A8ACA"))))